# Get number of characters in string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, char

I have an application, accepting a UTF-8 string of a maximum 255 **characters**.

If the characters are ASCII, (characters number == size in bytes).

If the characters are not all ASCII and contains Japanese letters for example, given the size in bytes, how can I get the number of characters in the string?

Input: `char *data, int bytes_no`
Output: `int char_no`

Comment: Are you using C or C++? I think we should be told

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm you can implement yourself, or is using a library (on which OS?) ok?

Comment: @DavidKernin UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, that is, it can be 8, 16, 24 or more bits.

Comment: You're right, it is multi-byte. Sorry, I'll delete the wrong info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mblen` to count the length or use `mbstowcs`

source:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mblen/

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#mod

> The number of characters can be counted in C in a portable way using
>   mbstowcs(NULL,s,0). This works for UTF-8 like for any other supported
>   encoding, as long as the appropriate locale has been selected. A
>   hard-wired technique to count the number of characters in a UTF-8
>   string is to count all bytes except those in the range 0x80 – 0xBF,
>   because these are just continuation bytes and not characters of their
>   own. However, the need to count characters arises surprisingly rarely
>   in applications.

you can save a unicode char in a wide char `wchar_t`

Comment: "need to count characters arises surprisingly rarely in applications" — so very true.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as "character".

Or, more precisely, what "character" is depends on whom you ask.

If you look in the [Unicode glossary](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/) you will find that the term has several not fully compatible meanings. As a *smallest component of written language that has semantic value* (the first meaning), `á` is a single character. If you take `á` and count *basic unit of encoding for the Unicode character encoding* (the third meaning) in it, you may get either one or two, depending on what exact representation (normalized or denormalized) is being used.

Or maybe not. This is a very complicated subject and nobody really knows what they are talking about.

Coming down to earth, you probably need to count code points, which is essentially the same as characters (meaning 3). `mblen` is one method of doing that, provided your current locale has UTF-8 encoding. Modern C++ offers [more C++-ish methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8), however, they are not supported on some popular implementations. Boost has [something of its own](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html) and is more portable. Then there are specialized libraries like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) which you may want to consider if your needs are much more complicated than counting characters.

Comment: Reading the OP, the very first thing I wondered was the meaning of "a UTF-8 string of a maximum 255 characters". Would that be 255 *bytes*, or 255 times the Unicode character "" (in UTF-8: `F0 9F 98 84`)?